# azure logic app compose action

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

In Azure logic apps I am creating a Json body in compose action. JSON structure is like below I am passing **place** property value as an variable i.e. `variables('result')`:

```
{
   "place": [
                {  "visit":"name"
                     },
               {    "visit":"name"
                     }
            ]
}
```

In **compose** action how to get the above structure  as i could not get the exact array like structure. I've tried a lot of things, but the result is like below:

```
{
       "place": "[
                    {  "visit":"name"
                         },
                   {    "visit":"name"
                         }
                ]"
 }
```

Double quotes are getting appended in the variable in compose action. If I pass as an array in **compose** means got like below double quotes is there in every element of array. I don't want doubles quotes inside array elements and I want the value as a variable in compose action's property:

```
{
           "place": [
                        "{  "visit":"name"
                             }",
                       "{    "visit":"name"
                             }"
                    ]
        }
 }
```

Please let me know hot to get the exact structure.

Comment: could you post your logic app json definition? Or at least the action that youre talking about please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your **result** variable is of type **array** and contains the following value (you can check this in your run history):

```
[
    "{\"visit\":\"London\"}",
    "{\"visit\":\"Paris\"}"
]
```

Note that I created my **result** variable using an expression - `createArray('{"visit":"London"}','{"visit":"Paris"}')`

You can add a **For each** that takes the **result** variable as its input.

Within the **For each** you can include a **Parse JSON** action that takes **Current item** as the Content. You will need to provide the schema of your array objects also.

`{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "visit": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}`

Outside of the **For each** loop you can then create a **Compose** action. The code view for the **Compose** action looks like this.

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "place": "@actionBody('Parse_JSON')"
    }
}
```

The output from this is the following:

```
{
    "place": [
        {
            "visit": "London"
        },
        {
            "visit": "Paris"
        }
    ]
}
```